# CommandButton Not getting executing

Tags: primefaces

I had the below form with two components:

1. Button
2. Dashboard - binded dynamically.

When I click the button, its action is not getting called.
So, to test it, I removed the "binding" attribute in dashboard, then the button method is getting called properly.
But I need to keep the binding, as I am framing the component dynamically.

Please suggest me, how to proceed.

```
<h:form id="frmDashbrd">
    <p:commandButton value="Non-Ajax Submit" action="#{dashboardBean.resetLayout}"   
        ajax="false" />  
    <p:dashboard id="dynamic_dashboard"  binding="#{dashboardBean.dashboard}">
    </p:dashboard>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using an actionListener in the commandButton?

Comment: Yes , Tried that one also . But no use.